How to extract ETL (Jobs) from SQL Server Management Studio
I want to extract the code from my Jobs (ETL) from my SQL Server 2014, which are in SQL Server Agent -> Jobs. I currently have more than 400, is there a faster way than entering each one and saving the code?

I have tried various codes from ChatGPT or Gemini and it does not work, it does not show me the codes that I have in each Job (ETL)
    DECLARE @jobname sysname, @filename varchar(255), @job_id uniqueidentifier, @sql nvarchar(max);

DECLARE job_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name, job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs;

OPEN job_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM job_cursor INTO @jobname, @job_id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @filename = CONCAT('C:\Scripts\Jobs\', @jobname, '.sql');

    -- Construct the command to generate the script of the job
    SET @sql = 'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_helpjob @job_id = ''' + CAST(@job_id AS varchar(36)) + ''';';

    -- Execute the command and redirect the output to a file, using Windows authentication
    EXEC xp_cmdshell CONCAT('sqlcmd -S your_server_name -d msdb -Q "', @sql, '" -o "', @filename, '"');

    FETCH NEXT FROM job_cursor INTO @jobname, @job_id;
END

CLOSE job_cursor;
DEALLOCATE job_cursor;


SSMS is only a UI - is it really relevant to the question?

Please show one of your code attempts. And please show sample data and desired results.

You can use SMO to extract the steps etc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job?view=sql-smo-160

Have a look at DbaTools.

In SSMS you can select multiple Jobs to be "extracted" into a single script:

In "Object Explorer" select "Jobs":



Press "F7" to open "Object Explorer Details" (you can also open it via View->Object Explorer Details):



Select all of the Jobs you want to export and right click to bring up a pop up menu. Select "Script Job As" and so on.


P.S. This trick works for many things
